# display pdf in browser using itext

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

i have modify a pdf with itext using pdfstamper. my application now create and save a new pdf file. i want to dipslay the pdf directly in the browser. Here my actual code

```
public static void test07(){
    try{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("c:\\temp\\file.pdf");
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\new.pdf"));
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

        //fill the fields

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

The question is: How should I modify this code and the servlet to display the pdf file in the browser?
I have already tried with ByteArrayOutputStream and response.getOutputStream but nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck! The book *iText in Action* contains a chapter that describes how to do exactly what you need. It's fairly straightforward: set the right headers on your response, and stream to the servlet's output stream.

Here's the link: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I try but nothing, the only way that i find is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968328/question-on-java-servlet-to-open-a-pdf-file-using-itext

Comment: So your problem is solved? If not, you'll have to show some more of your code because at this point it's very unclear what the problem is.